# Render different au-target-id in aurelia repeat

Tags: javascript, aurelia

During a `repeat.for` cycle my 'video' tag is being rendered with the same `au-target-id`. Not letting me reference a unique element to each item on list.

```
<div class="video-player flex-1" repeat.for="channel of selectedChannels">
   <div class="video-overlay-container"><span>${channel.name}</span></div>
   <video muted.bind="mute" element.ref="channel.el" loadeddata.trigger="onLoadeddata(channel)"
   play.trigger="onPlay()" pause.trigger="onPause()" timeupdate.trigger="onTimeUpdate(channel)">
   </video>
</div>
```

I was expecting to have different `au-target-id` on each `<video>` element, but all generate `<video>` elements have the same `au-target-id`

[image]

Comment: According to one answer found:
_The view compiler tags elements which have bindings, custom attributes or custom element behavior. Each gets an id so that it can be looked up in the compiled view's internal compilation instruction list whenever a new view instance needs to be created._

I have already tried different bindings and still could not render different ids for each element

Comment: Added an image with a `id.bind="channel.name"`, and as you can see, the au-target-id is still the same

Answer (score 3):

`id.bind="channel.name"` binds the channel.name to the id attribute and that works apparently (Dashcam Front and Dashcam Rear). The `au-target-id` has nothing to do with that. `au-target-id` is for Aurelia internals.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but according to the one of the Aurelia's Guru, the au-target-id will be different if different binding are associated to the element.
And as you can see, I need the element.ref binding to have total control of the element in future handlers, like load, play, pause videos.

Comment: Yes, but you have no control over the value au-target-id will get. 
But in the repeat.for you can use $index, to add a class to the video like class="video_$index" which gives you a unique class to target...

Comment: You are right! Thank you for your support. The problem was mine. Is not the Framework fault.